# AngularJS constants with some logic

Tags: angularjs, json, static

I have the following block of Constants in my AngularJS App

```
// Constants
.constant('config', {
    appName: 'MyApp',
    appVersion: 1.0,
    apiUrl: 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080'
});
```

The rest of the application uses the apiUrl Constant by using config.apiUrl. I want the following to happen

```
 // Constants
    .constant('config', {
        appName: 'MyApp',
        appVersion: 1.0,
        apiUrl:{"outer":"{'inner':{'key':'apValue'}}"}  
    });
```

I need to parse the JSON and provide the apiValue as the apiUrl. How can this be done with JavaScript in this file?

I want the clients to continue using config.apiUrl so all the parsing needs to be done in this file

Comment: you can access apiUrl like this : `apiUrl.outer.inner.key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do **JSON.parse** on the apiUrl string. Before that,
make sure the value of apiUrl is in a proper stringified JSON structure like below:

```
// Constants
.constant('config', {
    appName: 'MyApp',
    appVersion: 1.0,
    apiUrl:JSON.parse('{"outer":{"inner":{"key":"apiValue"}}}').‌​outer.inner.key
});
```

If you have the apiUrl as an object, do

```
JSON.stringify({"outer":{"inner":{"key":"apiValue"}}})
```

and assign it to **config.apiUrl**

So when you want to read the apiValue, you can get it as an object reference by doing :

```
JSON.parse(config.apiUrl);
```

More info on JSON methods [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: can I use JSON methods inside the constants declaration? Also I want the clients to continue using config.apiUrl so I want the parsing done with the final string in the constant apiUrl

Comment: Yes you can use it like this `{
    appName: 'MyApp',
    appVersion: 1.0,
    apiUrl:JSON.parse('{"outer":{"inner":{"key":"apiValue"}}}') 
}` **or** like this `{
    appName: 'MyApp',
    appVersion: 1.0,
    apiUrl:JSON.stringify({"outer":{"inner":{"key":"apiValue"}}}) 
}`

Comment: Thanks how can I parse and assign the value "apiValue" to the contsant apiUrl so I can still continue using config.apiUrl on the client side?

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer, if it is already parsed in the constants definition itself, you can refer it directly as `config.apiUrl.outer.inner.key` or if it is defined as a string in constant service, do a `JSON.parse(config.apiUrl)` and then read it as an object like above.

Comment: you're right I can read it as config.apiUrl.outer.inner.key but I want to read it as config.apiUrl , so in other words I need help making this assignment apiUrl =  outer.inner.key

Comment: also I receive the apiUrl value as mentioned so I want to convert it into a proper json, parse it, assign  the apiValue to the apiUrl constant

Comment: You can parse and refer it there itself like this `{
    appName: 'MyApp',
    appVersion: 1.0,
    apiUrl:JSON.parse('{"outer":{"inner":{"key":"apiValue"}}}').outer.inner.key
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I would try:

```
.constant('config', {
    appName: 'MyApp',
    appVersion: 1.0,
    // apiUrl:{"outer":"{'inner':{'key':'apiValue'}}"}
    apiUrl: JSON.parse({"outer":"{'inner':{'key':'apiValue'}}".replace("'", '"')}['outer'])['inner']['key']
});
```

Comment: It gives a syntax error because the inner JSON is not properly formatted.  If you format that properly with double quotes, it will work.